# how to make ngrx-store working with canLoad guard

Tags: angular, ngrx, ngrx-effects, ngrx-store-4.0

I don't know if this is a good practice or not though. But below is what I am trying to do:

I am having 2 lazy loaded modules: `ManagementModule` and `ConfigurationModule`, and the route config is as below:

```
const routes: Routes = [
  {path: '', redirectTo: 'management', pathMatch: 'full'}, {
    path: 'configuration',
    loadChildren: './configuration/configuration.module#ConfigurationModule',
    canLoad: [UnconfiguredGuard]
  },
  {
    path: 'management',
    loadChildren: './management/management.module#ManagementModule',
    canLoad: [ConfiguredGuard]
  }
]
```

Basically the idea was to check system status and redirect to different phases, eg. if sys is not configured yet, redirect to `/configuration`, otherwise, redirect to `/management`.

Before I added `@ngrx/store` into the project, the two `canLoad` guard are simple:

```
// ConfiguredGuard:
canLoad(route) {
  return this.configService.isConfigured()
        .do((configured: boolean) => {
          if (!configured) {
            // redirect to /configuration if unconfigured
            this.router.navigate(['/configuration']);
          }
        })
}
```

Now I want to adopt all @ngrx/{store,effects,router-store} libs, and the above guard is then changed to:

```
canLoad(route) {
    this.store.dispatch(new CheckInitStatus());
    return this.store.select('initStatus')
      .filter(s => s.checked) // check only when loaded
      .map(s => s.status === 'initialized')
      .catch(() => of(false));
}
```

of course, the side effect is defined:

```
  @Effect()
  check$: Observable<InitStatusAction> = this.actions$
    .ofType<CheckInitStatus>(CHECK_INITSTATUS)
    .mergeMap(() => this.fetchInitStatus())
    .map(status => new InitStatusChecked({status, checked: true}))
    .catch(e => of(new InitStatusCheckFailure(e)));
```

But the navigation was not happening, there's no `ROUTER_NAVIGATION` action emitted. Is anything I missed here? And also I am wondering whether this is a good practice? I did find some examples of `canActivate` guard usage, but none for `canLoad` guard. Please help, thanks!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I finally figured it out, after a whole day of debugging! The fix is quite simple though, add `first()` or `take(1)` into the operator chain after `filter()`, I cannot express the feeling I have now...but I do realize that I need a mindset change for using RxJS properly.

```js
canLoad(route) {
    this.store.dispatch(new CheckInitStatus());
    return this.store.select('initStatus')
      .filter(s => s.checked) // check only when loaded
      .first() // or equivalently take(1)
      .map(s => s.status === 'initialized')
      .catch(() => of(false));
}
```

I should read the examples of `canActivate` more carefully, this `take(1)/first()` operator is all there, for example: https://toddmotto.com/preloading-ngrx-store-route-guards

Comment: Hello @RoyLing! Thank you for this answer, it helped me a lot (I was with the same problem). Could you tell me where did you call route navigation? Do you call inside ngrx effects, inside componentes...w

Comment: @PedroArantes this was an issue in a past project a long time ago, I almost forgot what I was doing at the time...anyway, I think I was doing the navigation here in this guard itself, just following the example on angular doc. Hope it helps.